# How to set 2 functions with BeforeShowDay on jQuery Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a date picker and i need to set to functions to run on BeforeShowDay.

I can't work out how to run both functions names unavailable and disabledays

http://jsfiddle.net/rLnTQ/50/

Thanks in advance

Lee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about combining them into one?

```
function disabledays(date) {
dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == 0) {
    return [false, "", "Unavailable"]
} else {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 0 && day != 2)];
}
```

}

$('#txtDate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: disabledays
})

http://jsfiddle.net/rLnTQ/104/

Or you can put one within the other:

```
function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == 0) {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    } else {
        return disabledays(date);
    }
}

function disabledays(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 0 && day != 2)];


}

$('#txtDate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rLnTQ/118/

Comment: Thanks heaps :-).... i've been trying for about 2 hours with that.... can't believe i was so close

Comment: glad to help. how about a +1 & answered tag?

Comment: Done, do you have msn or skype something to keep in touch ?

Comment: thru the example I got my issue (related with beforeShowDay) working. Thanks